# Is $y > x$ or $y < x$ the converse of $x > y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

$G \subseteq A^2$

$G = \{(x|y): x > y\}$

$G^{-1} = \{(y|x): x > y\} =  \{(y|x): y > x\}$ **or** $G^{-1} = \{(y|x): y < x\}$ ?

The converse of the "greater than"-relation is the "lesser than"-relation, but does that mean the converse of $x > y$ is $y > x$? Or is the converse $y < x$? I think $y > x$ should be right, $y < x$ would essentially be the same relation?

However my actual problem is that I'm not quite sure how to interpret the set-builder notation in this case, how can I know what exactly is meant?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the *inverse* relationship?

Comment: @MartinR I mean the converse relation, as it's defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation).

Comment: If we have the relation $R = \{ (x,y) \mid x > y \}$, for the [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation) we have to switch $x$ and $y$: $R^T = \{ (y,x) \mid x > y \}$. Example with $\mathbb N$: $3 > 2$ and thus $(3,2) \in R$ and $(2,3) \in R^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that one possibility is the following: The inversion/transposing already happens when you exchange the roles of $x$ and $y$, that is if:
$$ R = \{(x,y) \in A^2 : \text{some term}(x,y) \} $$
you get the converse from flipping $x$ and $y$, that is
$$ R^{-1} = \{(y,x) \in A^2 : \text{the same term}(x,y) \} $$
Hence, in your case for
$$ G = \{(x,y) \in A^2: x > y \} $$
we have
$$ G^{-1} = \{(y,x) \in A^2: x > y\} = \{(y,x) \in A^2 : y < x \} $$
Note, that for the last term above we just rewrote the term such that $y$ and $x$ appear in the right order (that is in the same order as in the beginning.

You also can do inversion by flipping $x$ and $y$ in the term, that is for
$$ R = \{(x,y) \in A^2 : \text{term}(x,y) \} $$
you get the converse from flipping $x$ and $y$ in the term
$$ R^{-1} = \{(y,x) \in A^2 : \text{term}(y,x) \} $$
In our case: For
$$ G = \{(x,y) \in A^2: x > y \} $$
we have
$$ G^{-1} = \{(x,y) \in A^2: y > x\} = \{(x,y) \in A^2 : x < y \}. $$

In the end, note that if you flip $x$ and $y$ in both positions, you are just renaming variables, hence
$$ G = \{(x,y) \in A^2: x > y \} = \{(y,x) \in A^2: y > x \} $$

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is correct:$$G^{-1}=\{(y\mid x):x>y\}.$$However, after this you wrote that this set is equal to $\{(y\mid x):y>x\}$, which is false in general. And it makes no sense to write that $G^{-1}=\{(y\mid x):y<x\}$ until you define the meaning of $<$, which you did not do.

By the way, I think that a better choice of notation of $G$ would be $G=\{(x,y)\in A^2\mid x>y\}$, in which case$$G^{-1}=\left\{(y,x)\in A^2\mid x>y\right\}=\left\{(x,y)\in A^2\mid y>x\right\}.$$